# fatal error: sndfile.h.in: No such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, header, include

I was compiling with gcc on Linux
Because sndfile.h was not there but sndfile.h.in was found, I just tried with sndfile.h.in - which is in the same directory as the *.C file.

But I got the error even though it is in the same directory. Its been a while since I programmed in Linux that these little things are bothering me - appreciate if u could help me started.  Thanks

Comment: You probably need to run some `configure` script (itself generated by `autoconf` often in some `autogen.sh` script). You should tell which software you are trying to compile and give the exact commands. Probably that `sndfile.h.in` is a *template* generating `sndfile.h`

Comment: In the package the sources came with look around for a file called `INSTALL*` or `README*`. You'll propably find build instructions in there.

Comment: Thanks, Basile, alk and Karthikeyan.R.S: I had to run the ./configure and also change the angular brackets to "". Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using the angular brackets for the including the file.If you place `< >`. It will search in `/usr/include`. You have to use the double quotes for including the file in the current directory.  And be sure that file is available.

Like this.

```
 #include "sndfile.h.in"
```

Comment: Probably wrong. I guess `sndfile.h.in` is a template generating `sndfile.h`

Comment: Why are u thumbing down - "sndfile.h.in" is what caused the error msg. There might be other issues as Basile said. But thanks Karthikeyan.R.S - I am a newbie hence do not have privilege to give thumps up.